# Query with multiple left joins on tables with few rows exceeds max_join_size

Tags: mysql

I am making a website for my local soccer team, and on one page I would like to display some simple data for each team member (position on the field, number of games played, number of goals scored etc.). I tried to select all the needed data with one query to the database, because I've learned that minimizing the number of network calls is good for page load time. I thought I had succeeded at first, because everything displayed as I wanted, but now that we are a few matches into the season the page with the query displays the error: `The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows`. max_join_size is set to 4 000 000, so I think I am doing something horribly wrong in my query to have it return that many rows. I guess the query I wrote is a bit over my head, because I have a hard time visualizing it to really see what I am doing wrong. Maybe some of you could help me out? Here comes the query, and after I'll try to explain a little:

```
SELECT member_t.shirt_number, member_t.name, member_t.surname, pos_t.name AS position, pos_t.order_num AS posorder,
COUNT(DISTINCT m_m.match_id) AS matchnum, COUNT(DISTINCT goal_t.match_id, goal_t.internal_id) as goalnum, COUNT(DISTINCT assist_t.match_id, assist_t.internal_id) AS assistnum, COUNT(DISTINCT match_t.id) AS momnum, COUNT(DISTINCT yc_t.match_id, yc_t.internal_id) AS ycnum, COUNT(DISTINCT rc_t.match_id, rc_t.internal_id) AS rcnum
FROM team_member AS member_t
LEFT JOIN team_member_position AS pos_t ON member_t.position_id = pos_t.id
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT * FROM match_member WHERE match_member.match_id IN (SELECT id FROM football_match WHERE is_finished = 1)) AS m_m ON member_t.id = m_m.team_member_id
LEFT JOIN match_event_goal AS goal_t ON member_t.id = goal_t.team_member_id
LEFT JOIN match_event_goal AS assist_t ON member_t.id = assist_t.team_member_assist_id
LEFT JOIN football_match AS match_t ON member_t.id = match_t.mom_id
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT match_id, internal_id, team_member_id FROM match_event_card WHERE yc = 1) AS yc_t ON member_t.id = yc_t.team_member_id
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT match_id, internal_id, team_member_id FROM match_event_card WHERE rc = 1) AS rc_t ON member_t.id = rc_t.team_member_id
GROUP BY member_t.id
ORDER BY posorder ASC, name ASC
```

**The tables** (aliases)

`member_t`: one row for each team member. *6 columns, 21 rows*

`pos_t`: one row for each position on the field. *2 columns, 5 rows*

`m_m`: table to couple individual team members and individual matches. *2 columns, 72 rows*

`goal_t`/`assist_t`: one row for each goal in a match. *6 columns, 17 rows*

`match_t`: one row for each registered match. *9 columns, 6 rows*

`yc_t`/`rc_t`: one row for each carded player in a match. *6 columns, 10 rows*

So for `member_t` and `pos_t` I just select some columns (names, shirt numbers, positions etc.), while for the others I count the results to get totals (of games played, goals, red and yellow cards etc.). I join the same table twice a couple of times (for instance I first count goals, and then assists, with the help of the same table), don't know if this is a bad way to do it.

Maybe there is an obvious explanation. Please tell me if you need some more info. I hope you can help me find an effective way of gathering data for each team member. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not always a good idea to minimize number of queries. First, such queries are more difficult to maintain. Second, it is not always the case, that one big query will be more efficient then several smaller. It depends.

If you would execute several queries, like one per every statistic, getting it for all players at once, then that should be ok. It would be not ok if you would be doing a query per player.

Comment: Thank you. I'll follow your tip, seems like you won't be contested for most helpful answer :) Did I understand correctly:
1. Query once for each table with statistical data.
2. Query and loop through each team member, and find related data from previous queries.